# C# UDP Send and Receive Slow

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, unity-game-engine, udp

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out why I am having slow speeds while broadcasting data with UDP. For some reason I am getting a delay of over 6 seconds between computers. I am using threading for the sending and async for the reciever. I am using this in Unity and the packets are being broadcast on a local network. I am trying to build a P2P local network. The packet sizes are about 1500 bytes, and this was just a testing script I wrote but has a way to vary the packet sizes.

- I have already tried different ports
- I have tried a packet size of 15 bytes
- I am sending and recieveing on the same socket?
- It takes less than 1 ms to go to the same computer

I was wondering if there is a better way to send or receive the data. Or is there a buffer of data that I can't read to the end once I start to increase my speed? Is it my router?

## Sender Code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

public class NoiseSend : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Singleton
    private static NoiseSend instance = null;
    public static NoiseSend Instance { get { return instance; } }

    //Threading
    private Thread thread;
    private ManualResetEvent signal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private volatile bool isThreadRunning = false;
    public System.Threading.ThreadState tState;
    private Stopwatch sw;
    public string fps;

    //UDP Client
    private IPEndPoint broadcastIP;
    private UdpClient client;
    public int port = 2002;
    public int netID;

    //Data
    private string rnd;
    public int sizeVariable = 500;
    private string msg;
    public int packetSize;

    public DateTime get_UTCNow()
    {
        DateTime UTCNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        int year = UTCNow.Year;
        int month = UTCNow.Month;
        int day = UTCNow.Day;
        int hour = UTCNow.Hour;
        int min = UTCNow.Minute;
        int sec = UTCNow.Second;
        int mil = UTCNow.Millisecond;
        DateTime datetime = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, mil);
        return datetime;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null && instance != this)
        {
            //Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        setID();
        SetupUDP();
        StartThread();
    }

    private void SetupUDP()
    {
        client = new UdpClient();
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Broadcast;
        broadcastIP = new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
        client.Connect(broadcastIP);
    }

    private void setID()
    {
        string ip = LocalIPAddress();
        string[] tmp = ip.Split('.');
        netID = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[tmp.Length - 1]);
    }

    public string LocalIPAddress()
    {
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localIP = "";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                localIP = ip.ToString();
                return localIP;
            }
        }
        print("No Local IP Found?");
        return null;
    }

    public void StartThread()
    {
        if (!isThreadRunning)
        {
            signal.Reset();

            thread = new Thread(ContinuousThread);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Name = "Noise Send";
            thread.Start();
            isThreadRunning = true;
        }
        else
        {
            signal.Set();
        }
    }

    private void ContinuousThread(object param)
    {
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        while (!signal.WaitOne(0))
        {
            encodeData();
            byte[] encoded = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
            client.Send(encoded, encoded.Length);

            fps = (1000f / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString();
            sw.Stop();
            sw.Reset();
            sw.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
        client.Close();
        isThreadRunning = false;
    }

    private void encodeData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeVariable; i++)
        {
            rnd += i.ToString();
        }

        int min = get_UTCNow().Minute;
        int second = get_UTCNow().Second;
        int milisecond = get_UTCNow().Millisecond;

        msg = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}/", netID, rnd, min, second, milisecond);

        packetSize = msg.Length;
        rnd = "";
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Close();
        }
        signal.WaitOne(0);
        signal.Set();
        isThreadRunning = false;
    }
}
```

## Receiver Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class NoiseRecieve : MonoBehaviour
{
    //
    //Singleton
    private static NoiseRecieve instance = null;
    public static NoiseRecieve Instance { get { return instance; } }

    //FPS.
    private Stopwatch sw;
    public string fps;

    //UDP Client
    private IPEndPoint anyIP;
    private UdpClient client;
    public int port = 2002;
    private bool asyncListen = false;

    //Data
    private byte[] data;
    private string decoded;
    public int packetSize;
    public int packets;
    public List<RecievedData> input = new List<RecievedData>();

    public DateTime get_UTCNow()
    {
        DateTime UTCNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        int year = UTCNow.Year;
        int month = UTCNow.Month;
        int day = UTCNow.Day;
        int hour = UTCNow.Hour;
        int min = UTCNow.Minute;
        int sec = UTCNow.Second;
        int mil = UTCNow.Millisecond;
        DateTime datetime = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, mil);
        return datetime;
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null && instance != this)
        {
            //Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            instance = this;
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        SetupUDP();
        startAsync();
    }

    private void SetupUDP()
    {
        client = new UdpClient(port);
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Any;
        anyIP = new IPEndPoint(ip, 0);
    }

    private void startAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            asyncListen = true;
            client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            print(e);
        }
    }

    private void recv(IAsyncResult res)
    {

        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
        byte[] received = client.EndReceive(res, ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
        decoded = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
        decryptData(decoded);

        fps = (1000f / sw.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString();
        sw.Stop();
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();

        if (asyncListen)
        {
            client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(recv), null);
        }
    }

    private void decryptData(string decoded)
    {
        bool contains = false;
        List<string> msgs = decoded.Split('/').ToList();
        List<string> cleaned = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] tmp = msgs[i].Split(',');
            if (tmp.Length == 5)
            {
                cleaned.Add(msgs[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cleaned.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] tmp = cleaned[i].Split(',');
            int netID = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0]);
            if (!created(cleaned[i]))
            {
                input.Add(new RecievedData(netID));
            }
        }
        packets = cleaned.Count;
        packetSize = cleaned[0].Length;
    }

    private bool created(string data)
    {
        string[] tmp = data.Split(',');
        int tmpID = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0]);
        int min = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[2]);
        int sec = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[3]);
        int mil = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[4]);

        min -= get_UTCNow().Minute;
        sec -= get_UTCNow().Second;
        mil -= get_UTCNow().Millisecond;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            if (input[i].id == tmpID)
            {
                input[i].info = string.Format("min: {0} sec: {1} mil {2}", min, sec, mil);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Close();
        }
        asyncListen = false;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class RecievedData
    {
        public int id;
        public string info;

        public RecievedData(int i)
        {
            id = i;
            info = "first frame";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [A complete and *minimal* example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JamesKPolk I know this isnt "minimal" because of the amount of source code, however I did want to provide completed code samples so that anyone could go and test themselves and reproduce if possible

Comment: Download **hercules_3-2-6**. You need it for socket development. Use it to test your server and client individually. You will find if the server is the one taking so long to send or if the client is the one taking so long to receive data.

Comment: Disable your antivirus and firewall applications, including windows firewall, and test again.